# Difficulties implementing DSL in Prolog from EBNF using DCG

Tags: parsing, prolog, dsl, dcg, ebnf

I'm working on implementation of the Google Protobuf compiler for **proto** files in Prolog for generating Prolog programs. Prolog is **SWI-Prolog**.

I'm translating **EBNF** definitions into DCG and ran across a few problems:

1. I have to deal with `[ ... ]` and `{ ... }` EBNF construct - meaning  `optional` ( executable zero or one times ) and `repeatative`( executable any number of times );
2. I have to insert the *callbacks* into DCG code to implement the part of compiler functionality (syntax switching/importing/ etc.) using DCG's construct `{ ... }`, which allows goals in Prolog syntax inside DCG rules.

I'm applying for `optional` and `repeatative` the meta-predicates: `$$rep/1`, `$$opt/1`:

```
EBNF
decimals  = decimalDigit { decimalDigit }
exponent  = ( "e" | "E" ) [ "+" | "-" ] decimals 

DCG
decimals  --> decimalDigit, '$$rep'( decimalDigit ).
exponent  --> ( "e"; "E" ), '$$opt'( "+"; "-" ), decimals.

'$$rep'( Goal ) :- repeat, call(Goal); !, fail.

'$$opt'( Goal ) :- once(Goal) ; \+ Goal.

"Callback:"
import --> "import", opt(( "weak" ; "public", { record(public)} )), strLit,
{
     import(public, strlit )
}, ";".
```

Looking awkward (if not to say ugly) for me...

**Questions:**

What's wrong with my solutions?

Should I manually translate EBNG into DCG without using meta-predicates?

What is the alternative for the awkward penetration into a DCG rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a quick first glance, the main issue is that you are uncleanly **intermingling** DCGs with regular Prolog predicates.

Stay within DCGs to define all nonterminals. For example:

```
optional(NT) --> [] | NT.

once_or_more(NT) --> NT, or_more(NT).

or_more(NT) --> [] | NT, or_more(NT).
```

With the following example definition:

```
a --> [a].
```

We can post:

```
?- phrase(optional(a), Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [a].

?- phrase(once_or_more(a), Ls).
Ls = [a] ;
Ls = [a, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, a, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, a, a, a] .
```

This seems to work as you need it.

For the callback, you can simply pass around the predicate that you need to call, with the general outline:

```
parse_with_callback(Goal) -->
        ...,
        { Goal },
        ...
```

This seems quite OK.

If such patterns arise frequently, you can always consider *generating* such DCGs from a different representation that lets you represent the task more cleanly.

Comment: Late thanks for your reply. It worth noting that `repeatatives` (zero or more ) usually is something like this:  decimals([]) --> []. decimals([ D | Ds ]) --> decimal(D), !, decimals(Ds).

Comment: You're welcome! Using `!/0` prevents you from using the grammar in all directions, such as for *generating* answers. This would be possible if you generalized `decimal//1`.